# Why does not nympy.nanmin() find the correct value

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I met some strange behaviour from `Pandas` and/or `NumPy`, could you please help to find out my mistake?

I read a data from the [file](https://yadi.sk/d/Yz1hs0Xa3GYMgD), then replace all non numeric elements with `np.nan`, then calculate max and min values with `np.nanmin()` and `np.nanmax()`. Those values are `nan`, though there're some floats in the column.

There are two points I discover:

1) If I get min value in interactive mode with `np.nanmin(df.iloc[:cnt_row,cnt_col])` when the last element of the column is float (in other way, `cnt_row - 1` points to a float element), the function returns a correct value. But if there's a `nan` in the end of the range, the function returns `nan`, though there are floats in previous positions.

2) When I save a DataFrame with replaced text values to a new csv file and read it again, `np.nanmin` and `nanmax` work perfect.
Here's the code I use:

```
def is_digit(val):
    if type(val) == str:
        val = val.replace(',', '.')
    try:
        return not math.isnan(float(val))
    except:
        return False

path = "C:/test/deposits1.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', header=0)
rows_num = len(df.iloc[:, 0])
cols_num = len(df.columns)
cnt_row = 0
cnt_col = 0
for cnt_col in range(cols_num):
    # remove text from columns containing digits
    for cnt_row in range(0, rows_num):
        if not is_digit(df.iloc[cnt_row, cnt_col]):
            df.iloc[cnt_row, cnt_col] = np.nan
        else:
            val = df.iloc[cnt_row, cnt_col]
            if type(val) == str:
                val = val.replace(',', '.')
            df.iloc[cnt_row, cnt_col] = float(val)       

    min_val = None
    max_val = None    
    try:
        min_val = np.nanmin(df.iloc[:, cnt_col].values)
        max_val = np.nanmax(df.iloc[:, cnt_col].values)
    except: pass
```

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the issue you are facing, including sample input and expected output.

Comment: The input file is here: https://yadi.sk/d/Yz1hs0Xa3GYMgD, the expected output is min_val = 200, max_val = 5000000

Comment: I strongly suggest using pandas' methods: `df.min` will skip nan-like values by default. Do you really need all that extra work and double loops?

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'm trying to replace loops with some expressions, but the task is not easy for me - a slice contains empty elements, text, numbers and sometimes numbers in a string format with ',' instead of '.', so I need to replace symbols and convert strings to numbers. I tryed df.min, but it doesn't work preperly (returns empty list)